# Don't connect java client SignalR in honor phone

Tags: android, signalr

I have a chat application that work with signalr library.
every thing is ok. but in honor devices like honor 10 lite don't connect signalr.
Do you have any solution?

Comment: Any errors or a sample of code , or something?

Comment: we can't solve this and we can't help you solve this with the information you've provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem cause! 
In android version 9 we need network permission
I create an xml file

```
 <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">myHubURl.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
```

and in manifest :
        `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`